# Rewrite a script so it takes option arguments to control its behaviour

Tags: linux, bash, unix, ubuntu

I created a script and it moves files with different extensions to their specified directories.
If the directory is not there, it creates another one (where the files will go), and it creates another directory where the remaining files with different extensions will go.

My first problem is that I want when I put `-d` and full path on the terminal it should move only media files, `-l` and full path to move all text files, then `-x` to change the extension to uppercase, then `-u` to lowercase.

Can somebody modify it for me and show me how to overcome this problem?

```
#!/bin/bash
From="/home/elg19/lone/doc"
To="/home/elg19/mu"
WA="/home/elg19/du"
MA="/home/elg19/dq"
WQ="/home/elg19/d2"


# this function checks if the directory exits and creates one if it does not then moves all doc files 

function mama(){
if [[ ! -d "$WA" ]]; then
      mkdir -p "$WA"
fi
cd "$From"
for i in pdf txt doc; do
  find . -type f -name "*.${i}" -exec mv "{}" "$WA" \;
done
}

# this function checks if the directory exits and creates one if it does not then moves all media files 

function so(){
if [[ ! -d "$To" ]]; then
      mkdir -p "$To"
fi
cd "$From"
for i in mp3 mp4 swf; do
  find . -type f -name "*.${i}" -exec mv "{}" "$To" \;
done
}

# this function checks if the directory exits and creates one if it does not then moves all image files 

function soa(){
if [[ ! -d "$MA" ]]; then
      mkdir -p "$MA"
fi
cd "$From"
for i in jpg gif png; do
  find . -type f -name "*.${i}" -exec mv "{}" "$MA" \;
done
}

# this function checks if the directory exits and creates one if it does not then moves all the remaining files 

function soaq(){
if [[ ! -d "$WQ" ]]; then
      mkdir -p "$WQ"
fi
cd "$From"
for i in *; do
  find . -type f -name "*.${i}" -exec mv "{}" "$WQ" \;
done
}
mama
so
soa
soaq
```

Comment: What is the question? Did you consider using `getopt` and friends  http://aplawrence.com/Unix/getopts.html

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Yea he is asking about setting up option flags. I think your link is better than really a short answer could do. If he just reads that he will easily be able to solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if the options suggested are mnemonic in your native language, but they are counter-mnemonic in English.  I would suggest something more like:

```
-m path    Move media files
-t path    Move text files
-u         Change extensions to upper-case
-l         Change extensions to lower-case
```

The command to use for regular argument parsing like this is [`getopts`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/getopts.html) (plural - many systems also have a command `getopt`, singular, which has different characteristics altogether).

The referenced page gives an example of how to use it:

> The following example script parses and displays its arguments:

```
aflag=
bflag=
while getopts ab: name
do
    case $name in
    a)    aflag=1;;
    b)    bflag=1
          bval="$OPTARG";;
    ?)   printf "Usage: %s: [-a] [-b value] args\n" $0
          exit 2;;
    esac
done
if [ ! -z "$aflag" ]; then
    printf "Option -a specified\n"
fi
if [ ! -z "$bflag" ]; then
    printf 'Option -b "%s" specified\n' "$bval"
fi
shift $(($OPTIND - 1))
printf "Remaining arguments are: %s\n" "$*"
```

The option `-a` doesn't take an argument; the option `-b` requires an argument.

Comment: Which parts don't you understand?  The code is from the manual page for `getopts` at the POSIX web site.  You can treat `printf` a bit like `echo`; it's a hybrid between the C language `printf()` and `echo`.